# Como faço o select no Mysql para obter este resultado

Tags: mysql

Tenho 3 tabelas, gostaria que o retorno do select venha com valor 0 quando não estiver na tabela relacionada.

[Exemplo tas tabelas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vTtO.jpg)

o exemplo mostra os dados de opção que contém na tabela enquete, mais gostaria q mostre 0 se não contém na tabela enquete.

Essas tabelas são referente a uma pesquisa de satisfação, Gostaria de Obter o resultado do select para inserir no Chart.

tem varias perguntas e 3 opções para escolhe, tenho que mostrar conforme a imagem a baixo, mesmo se ñ tiver voto tenho que mostrar o nome.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Basta escolher o Join correto, e usar `coalesce(coluna, 0)`. Você pode aprender mais sobre JOINs [aqui mesmo no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70).

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro que não tem nenhuma pergunta não respondida, então inclui uma para o teste:

```
INSERT INTO `pergunta` (`id_pergunta`, `titulo`, `status`) VALUES
  ('5', 'O que achou da sua Pergunta ?', '1'),
  ('6', 'O que achou do Ambiente ?', '1'),
  ('7', 'O que achou do Atendimento ?', '1'),
  ('8', 'O que achou do tempo de Espera ?', '1');
```

Depois acertei o select:

```
SELECT p.id_pergunta AS 'Pergunta', o.titulo AS 'Opcao', COUNT(o.titulo) AS 'Total'
FROM enquete e
RIGHT JOIN pergunta p ON p.id_pergunta = e.id_pergunta
LEFT JOIN opcao o ON o.id_opcao = e.id_opcao
GROUP BY e.id_pergunta, o.titulo
```

Comment: Raoni, existe um link "Editar" ali, acredito que você já possua esse privilégio.